# How to save & load images using VB 6

Tags: sql-server-2005, vb6

Im using VB 6 with SQL Server 2005. I have set the data type of the subject field in the database to 'Image'. When I save an image from the picture control, it is displayed as binary on the DB. Im however unable to load the binary file from the DB to the picture control. How do I programatically save and load an image using the picture control?

Answer (score 1):

It might not apeal to you, but in such scenarios I typically dump the bytes to a temp file and then use the standard VB6 LoadImage to go from disk into the image object.  Of course, you should then delete the temp file afterwards.  This is the only way I know of without using Win APIs and/or custom type libraries.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simplistic example that loads a picture from a recordset (RS) into an image control (Image1):

```
Set strStream = New ADODB.Stream
strStream.Type = adTypeBinary
strStream.Open

strStream.Write RS.Fields("**YourImageField**").Value

strStream.SaveToFile "C:\Temp.bmp", adSaveCreateOverWrite
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Temp.bmp")
Kill ("C:\Temp.bmp")
```